# How I can check gzip decoding time in the web browser?

Tags: javascript, browser

I want to check the performance of the gzip decoding speed in a web browser.
In the Java or c#, we can easily check the gzip decoding time.
But I can not measure the decoding time in the web browser.

plz help me.
I want to check some decoding speed of gzipped html files.
With JavaScript can I measure the performance.

Comment: I think the time it takes to decompress the data is neglectable. Or what amounts of data do you sent to your client that you worry about that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to get that time, especially in your own Javascript code : I suppose the decompression is done at a much lower-level *(like somewhere arround the download/network layer of the browser)* than the rendering of the page the execution of your Javascript code.

That would be the best solution for that compression to be totally transparent for the upper-layers : when rendering pages or executing JS code, there is absolutely no need for the browser to know that it's been received in a compressed form.

Maybe a solution, especially with Firefox, would be to develop some extension ?

Considering Firebug, for example, is able to kind of "*hook*" into the network layer, to display the information we get in the "*Network*" tab, I suppose you might be able to do sort of the same ?

Answer (score 1):

In open source browsers like Chromium or Firefox you could have a look at the source code and insert some lines to record the time needed for decoding. If the browser uses a specific library for gzip decoding, you can of course also download that library and test it.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome, you can check out the various properties of `chrome.loadTimes()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) - it has a time display for each HTTP transaction. Because Fiddler is a debugging proxy, it works with any browser.  Windows only, though.